# deployment manager Cloud SQL

Tags: jinja2, google-cloud-sql, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to create CloudSQL Instance with Failover Replica using Deployment Manager.

I am able to create a Read Replica but couldn't create Failover Replica.

Can you please provide me a Deployment Manager Script or suggest me with the changes to the code below:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/sqladmin/jinja

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha) you have a tutorial on how to create a CloudSQL database with high availability  (Master + Failover replica).

For this purpose the Deployment Manager doesn't really make a difference. I will go on how to create the database and replica with the gcloud SDK, if you want to use the console it's explained on the link I provided.

Create the database and replica from the Cloud Shell with this command:

```
gcloud sql instances create [MASTER INSTANCE NAME]  --enable-bin-log --backup-start-time=00:01 --failover-replica-name=[FAILOVER INSTANCE NAME]
```

Check the rest of the options for [gcloud sql instances create here.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/create) You need the flags --enable-bin-log enabled for this, and as you have binary logs you need to enable the backups. The "backup-start-time=" is in UTC time.

NOW, the main issue you are facing is that you want to modify that template to deploy a master and failover replica, but the template is deploying a FIRST GENERATION instance (see the "replicationType: SYNCHRONOUS" value), and the failover replica is limited to SECOND GENERATION instances.

The API request for what you are trying to accomplish would go something like this:

```
{
 "name": "master-db",
 "settings": {
  "tier": "db-n1-standard-1",
  "backupConfiguration": {
   "binaryLogEnabled": true,
   "startTime": "00:01",
   "enabled": true
  }
 },
 "failoverReplica": {
  "name": "failover-db"
 }
}
```

Check the [sqladmin API explorer page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/sqladmin/sqladmin/v1beta4/) to explore the different possible values easily. Afterwards converting the calls to a jinja template should be easy.

Comment: Glad to hear that ;)