# Unable to set high availability for Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to create Cloud SQL using Deployment Manager.

Most of my configuration works apart from settings.availabilityType

**jinja file** -- That works

```
resources:
- name: dev-01
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances
  properties:
    backendType: SECOND_GEN
    instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
    region: europe-west1
    databaseVersion: POSTGRES_9_6
    settings: 
      tier: db-custom-1-3840
      storageAutoResize: true
      dataDiskSizeGb: PD_SSD
      dataDiskType: 10
      replicationType: SYNCHRONOUS
      failoverReplica:
        available: true
      backupConfiguration:
        enabled: true
      locationPreference:
        zone: europe-west1-b
      activationPolicy: ALWAYS
```

**jinja file --** That doesn't work

```
resources:
- name: dev-01
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances
  properties:
    backendType: SECOND_GEN
    instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
    region: europe-west1
    databaseVersion: POSTGRES_9_6
    settings: 
      tier: db-custom-1-3840
      storageAutoResize: true
      dataDiskSizeGb: PD_SSD
      dataDiskType: 10
      replicationType: SYNCHRONOUS
      failoverReplica:
        available: true
      backupConfiguration:
        enabled: true
      locationPreference:
        zone: europe-west1-b
      activationPolicy: ALWAYS
      availabilityType: REGIONAL
```

I am getting error... Invalid API call...

**EDIT#1**

From the GUI I can add the HA with one click and without any existing failover instances.

[image]

Comment: Nikhil Gupta I have answered below. Does it work? If so please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are trying to deploy a HA configuration with a locationPreference. The gcloud command to create HA for Cloud SQL HA instance just expects region and failover related details. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha#ha-create)

Follow this [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/cloudsql) and you will find some good samples out there.

Specifically [this part of the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/58b4d5db56081f9a9c0dd595a9ef264e4f6389ae/examples/v2/cloudsql/cloudsql.jinja#L57) gives you the template to follow

Comment: I understand the failover concept but my question is when i create a Cloud SQL instance via Deployment Manager without availabilityType setting it gets created successfully and then from the GUI I can simple enable High Availability without any failover instance. So why can't I do it via Deployment Manager.

Comment: The above answer has an example . Did you try?

Comment: Prashant, I know the example in the git repo works... but that doesn't answer my question. In the example a failover is being created explicitly on the other hand once I create an DB instance via Deployment Manger I can enable HA from GUI without any failover and also the locationPreference preference is already set... so why is this deviation...

Comment: the deviation is because through the UI you are doing 2 operations (two API calls) whereas DM is making a single API call. As @Preshant mentioned, the API call for a failover SQL cluster should only have a specified region, not zone. The error returned should mention something along these lines

Answer (score 1):

Another user had a similar issue to yours in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513731/deployment-manager-cloud-sql).
That worth to take a look, especially [Jordi Miralles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9176789/jordi-miralles) answer

For additional information, you should take a look into GCP docs.

- [Overview of the high availability configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability)
- [Enabling and disabling high availability on an instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha)
- [Cloud SQL instance resource](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the edit note, the regional availability configuration (the one for PostgreSQL) does not require a failover instance, since it's based on regional persistent disks. More info on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability).

Failover instances were only for MySQL instances, and it's [now considered legacy (and the docs imply it's going to be deprecated in 2020)](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#legacy_mysql_high_availability_option) in favor of the same HA system as PostgreSQL: [regional persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability).

Comment: Thanks Jofre for the info, do u also know why can't I use the availabilityType attribute in my jinja...